# Include rev number with diff?

Tags: svn

Is there a way to include the revision number of each file returned when using

```
svn diff -r REV1:REV2 --summarize <URL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just change format of command and use PEG-revisions

`svn diff --summarize <URL@REV1> <URL@REV2>`

Edit:

`--summarize` produces only **list of affected in range** (changes in **end compared to start**) files

If you want get **list of files per prevision** in range, you have to use `svn log -v -q` (or use diff without --summarize)

Comment: I tried that, but I still get the same results, with no revision number.  Example output: A       http://SVNURL//conf/pa/log4j.properties

Comment: Using svn log -v -q gives me all of the log entries for every file, which I don't need.  Maybe I need to simplify this request.  Is there a way I can get the revision number for every file in the project, like this:  javaclass.class revision 1, javaclass2.class revision 2, javaclass3.class revision 1, etc.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak - `svn ls -R -v <URL>` ?

Comment: that last option will work.  I can pipe the output to a text file, and then open it in Excel and sort it to get what I need.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Would `svn blame` be of any use? That would show you what line was changed by a particular revision.

Otherwise, you could pipe the output of the `svn diff` to `svn info`:

```
$ svn diff --summarize -r$rev1:rev2 $REPO_URL | while read status url
do
    echo $url
    svn info $url | grep "Last Changed Rev:"
done
```

The output will look something like this:

```
http://svn.vegicorp.com/trunk/project1/file1.txt
Last Changed Rev: 157264
http://svn.vegicorp.com/trunk/project1/file2.txt
Last Changed Rev: 157264
http://svn.vegicorp.com/trunk/project1/file3.txt
Last Changed Rev: 157264
http://svn.vegicorp.com/trunk/project1/file4.txt
Last Changed Rev: 157264
http://svn.vegicorp.com/trunk/project1/file5.txt
Last Changed Rev: 157264
```

If you need the revision and URL of the file on the same line, you could use `printf`. If you're not on a Unix system, you can use [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org) to give you the BASH shell and most of the standard Unix-like utilities you need to do this type of manipulation. Otherwise, you'll need to turn to PowerShell, Perl, or Python, and program it.